# The type must implement the inherited pure virtual template method

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates, eclipse-cdt, pure-virtual

i have a class template with a pure-virtual method:

OneWireSensor.h:

```
template <typename T>
class OneWireSensor {
public:
    OneWireSensor(std::string OneWireFilePath) : FileName(OneWireFilePath + "/w1_slave") {};
    virtual T Read() = 0;
    virtual ~OneWireSensor() {};

protected:
    string w1_slave()
    {
        ...
    }

private:
    const string FileName;
};
```

and I have a subclass, which implements the pure-virtual methods:

DS18B20.h:

```
#include <map>
#include "OneWireSensor.h"


class DS18B20 : public OneWireSensor<double>
{
public:
  DS18B20(std::string OneWireFilePath);
  virtual  ~DS18B20();

  virtual double Read();
  static std::map<string, DS18B20> ReadConnectedSensors(std::string OneWireBasePath);
};
```

DS18B20.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "DS18B20.h"


DS18B20::DS18B20(std::string OneWireFilePath) : OneWireSensor(OneWireFilePath)
{ }


DS18B20::~DS18B20()
{ }

double DS18B20::Read()
{
  string token = "t=";
  string flash = this->w1_slave();
  size_t pos = flash.find(token);
  size_t nl = flash.find("\n", pos+1);
  string temperature = flash.substr(pos + token.length(), nl);

  double retVal = std::stod(temperature);

  return retVal/1000;
}

std::map<string, DS18B20> DS18B20::ReadConnectedSensors(std::string OneWireBasePath)
{
  ...
}
```

Now my problem:
I'm using [Gnu Toolchain for Raspberry from SysProgs](http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/tutorial/), which works fine. And also this code is compiled and linked without any problems.

But Eclipse CDT tells me:
*The type 'DS18B20' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'OneWireSensor::Read'*

at this line in main.cpp:
`DS18B20 Sensor("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000004027c9f");`

I don't want to disable the CDT parser for such errors. I want to make the CDT parser to correctly detect the implementation.

Any idea?

Comment: What if you did this? `virtual double OneWireSensor<double>::Read();`

Comment: `virtual double OneWireSensor<double>::Read();` is not compilable. But after I've undone this changes, eclipse did no more show this error. So I think it was just a refresh error, which which eclipse saved over restarts...
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It's compilable for me though. Using Visual Studio 2013.